# Using paste() within a summary() call for linear regression models

Tags: r

For each of 100 data sets, I am using `lm()` to generate 7 different equations and would like to extract and compare the p-values and adjusted R-squared values.

Kindly assume that `lm()` is in fact the best regression technique possible for this scenario.

In searching the web I've found a number of useful examples for how to create a function that will extract this information and write it elsewhere, however, my code uses `paste()` to label each of the functions by the data source, and I can't figure out how to include these unique pasted names in the function I create.

Here's a mini-example:

```
temp <- data.frame(labels=rep(1:10),LogPre= rnorm(10))
temp$labels2<-temp$labels^2
testrun<-c("XX")

for (i in testrun)
{
  assign(paste(i,"test",sep=""),lm(temp$LogPre~temp$labels))
  assign(paste(i,"test2",sep=""),lm(temp$LogPre~temp$labels2))
}
```

I would then like to extract the coefficients of each equation

But the following doesn't work:

```
summary(paste(i,"test",sep="")$coefficients)
```

and neither does this:

```
coef(summary(paste(i,"test",sep="")))
```

Both generating the error :$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
EVEN THOUGH

```
summary(XXtest)$coefficients
```

and

```
coef(summary(XXtest))
```

work just fine.

How can I use `paste()` within `summary()` to allow me to do this for AAtest, AAtest2, ABtest, ABtest2, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to tell exactly what your purpose is, but some kind of apply loop may do what you want in a simpler way.  Perhaps something like this?

```
temp <- data.frame(labels=rep(1:10),LogPre= rnorm(10))
temp$labels2<-temp$labels^2

testrun<-c("XX")
names(testrun) <- testrun

out <- lapply(testrun, function(i) {
  list(test1=lm(temp$LogPre~temp$labels),
       test2=lm(temp$LogPre~temp$labels2))
})
```

Then to get all the p-values for the slopes you could do:

```
> sapply(out, function(i) sapply(i, function(x) coef(summary(x))[2,4]))
                XX
test1 0.02392516
test2 0.02389790
```

Comment: I don't actually want the coefficients themselves, I want to be able to isolate the p-values that are in that output- probably by writing that to a dataframe and isolating the 4th column thereof.

Answer (score 3):

Just using `paste` results in a character string, not the object with that name. You need to tell R to get the object with that name by using `get`.

```
summary(get(paste(i,"test",sep="")))$coefficients
```

Comment: A<- summary(get(paste(i,"test",sep=""))$coefficients)
B<- coef(summary(get(paste(i,"test",sep=""))))    @Aaron- why would these return two different things?

Comment: @Nan: A is the summary of the coefficients; B is the coefficients from the summary.  Though my first answer used A, it's most likely meaningless.  I've edited it to use B.  Thanks for catching that.